# Instantiate object from browserify-bundled NPM package in JavaScriptCore in Swift

Tags: swift, npm, browserify, javascriptcore

I have bundled up an NPM package using Browserify. Then, I import it into Swift

```
 guard let npmPackage = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mynpmpackage", ofType: "js") else {
            print("Unable to read resource file")
            return nil
}


npmContent = try String(contentsOfFile: npmPackage, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

let jsSource = "var window = this; \(npmContent)"
// I also tried executing npmContent directly below:
context?.evaluateScript(jsSource)
```

Then I want to create an instance of the NPM object, would I need to pass it into the Javascriptcore function?

I don't seem to be able to access the browserify bundled objects, how can I create an instance?

```
    let jsCode =
"""
async function lookupDataUsingNPMPackage(myaddress, callback, alc) {
            try {
                const config = {
                  apiKey: "myapikey",
                  network: "mynetwork",
                };
                const myInstance = new mynpmpackage(config);
                console.log("hola")
                const { data } = await fetch(myInstance.data.getDataForOwner(myaddress));
                callback(data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log( error);
            }
        };
    """
```

Comment: From what you posted it looks like you're just reading the JS file as text into a string. You will need to execute it, perhaps with JavaScriptCore as you mentioned. Are you already doing so? Could you include that code in your question?

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look at this, I only added minimum stuff because when I posted the full code nobody looked at it. Another version of the Code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817895/how-to-await-async-js-function-inside-swift-using-javascriptcore-and-callback

Comment: Ok you should close this as a duplicate of that issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to await async JS function inside Swift using JavaScriptCore and Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817895/how-to-await-async-js-function-inside-swift-using-javascriptcore-and-callback)